# Using an AWS database that can store more than 65,535 bytes in a row

Tags: mysql, amazon-rds

I have a MySQL Barracuda table with about 150 fields and most of them are TEXT types.

1. If I wanted to store more than 65,535 characters in a row, would it be possible to do so using Amazon's AWS database ? If so which kind of database ? RDS ?
2. I am using a semi-VPS kind-of hosting company which has the application in vanilla PHP connected to this database. Would it be possible to migrate just the database to AWS and keep the application running on my hosting company ? (I should be able to connect to this AWS database from my host's PHP application.

Comment: Yes you can access a database at AWS over the internet, but you most likely should not. It will add lots of latency and might make the connection unstable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

(Addressing Q1)

There are many workarounds for having bloated columns.  Let's tackle that.

What is the table's `ROW_FORMAT`?  `DYNAMIC` and `COMPACT` work differently.

Do they all need to be `TEXT`?  Or can some be `VARCHAR` with low limits?  (Eg: `name TEXT` --> `name VARCHAR(60)`)

Consider "vertical partitioning".  This is where you split a table into 2 tables -- putting some columns in each table.  They would have the same `PRIMARY KEY` (except not both being `AUTO_INCREMENT`).

Do any of the columns have repeated values?  If so, consider normalizing.  (Eg, `country TEXT` -> `country_code CHAR(2) CHARACTER SET ascii` with values like 'US', 'ES', 'UK', 'IN'.)

Have you splayed an array across columns?  That is a no-no.  Turn that set of columns into rows in a related table.  (Eg home_phone, work_phone, fax, cell.)

Please provide `SHOW CREATE TABLE` with the actual column names; we may have more hints.  (And some of my suggestions above may be painfully obvious.)

After looking at the schema...

I see a bunch of columns that sounds like money or other numeric stuff, but is in `VARCHAR(25)`; consider changing to `INT` or some other numeric datatype

I see about 80 each of `TEXT` and `VARCHAR`.  This does stress some builtin limits in InnoDB.  But they can, and need to be, worked around:

Plan A:  Vertical partitioning -- break out FR, COP, PP, Customer, etc. into a few extra tables.  Use `JOIN` to re-gather the data.

Plan B:  Throw most of the columns into a large `JSON` text column.  Or maybe one for FR, one for Customer, etc.  Most app languages can easily parse JSON.

Since you have only one index (on `id`) I guess there is no call for searching the table?  A few other columns, like maybe userID and name, should be kept in their own columns, and possibly indexed.

Comment: Its DYNAMIC.

Most of them are TEXT because it's a questionnaire kind of website.

And now I am implementing TinyMCE for HTML formatting which is the reason for more characters (HTML tags).

Comment: @anjanesh 150 columns?  Do not splay an array (of questions? of answers?) across columns.  Make another table with probably only one `TEXT` column and a couple of numbers (eg, `question_id`).  Then multiple rows for multiple Answers.

Comment: @anjanesh - To discuss further, please provide `SHOW CREATE TABLE`.

Comment: https://pastebin.com/zmxS4cqa

Comment: @anjanesh - I added to my Answer.

Comment: Regarding changing VARCHAR(25) to INT : Users have entered values like
Approximately 25,000
More than 10,000
36,180 health clubs
22,969 Laundromats
Nearly 20,000
10,000'S

Comment: @anjanesh -- OK.  But don't try to do arithmetic or numerical comparisons on varchars.